# Npm package in Django isn't working on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, npm

I installed a package using npm in my Django app and then moved the folder to my static folder and imported it to base.html with `<script src="/static/js/convertapi-js/lib/convertapi.js"></script>`
This works fine on localhost but when I deploy the app to Heroku it can't find the file.
I'm new to Django so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that you committed that file and deploy your static folder to heroku?

Comment: Yes, all of my other static files are working as they should.